# How can I create an event on a selection on panolens js?

Tags: javascript

I am using panolens for my project. I have a few problems hoping everyone can help.

I know it is possible to position infospot object in panolens like this:

infospot = new PANOLENS.Infospot (500, '');
infospot.position.set (-100, -500, -5000);

I want to capture the event on a rectangular or circular selection on the panorama ... not on a location like the infospot.

Hope everybody help please.

My english is not good, please ignore it.

Comment: what is panolens, please add a reference of it

Comment: Hi @MisterJojo , reference of it here : https://pchen66.github.io/Panolens/